# How to use @Body and @Path and @Query sametime together in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I want to use @Body and @Path and @Query Sametime together in android with POST Request but don't get any response from server and get correctly response in Postman!

my sample URL:
`{{domain}}/api/Mobile/FTR2/JkVqzeqQ82?version=2.4.0`

I don't know how do it??

I know @Body work POST Request and i send like:

```
{
"currentItems":[]
}
```

by @Body to server and send 2.4.0 by @Query